How can I add structured metadata to a column in an iceberg table?
We are making a new icerberg table. We need to associate to each column of the table a set of "metadata", such as units, description, author, etc. So, we would like to represent this metadata as a map (or json) and associated it to each column. Could we add it to the metadata JSON file that is part of the metadata layer?
Is there a way to solve it?
I read the documentation but I could not find a solution. We would like to get a solution.
